# Using ClientWebSocket for Secured(SSL) connection to Websocket server

Tags: c#, ssl, websocket

I tried to do googling for example code for echo client which supports SSL (and proxy) in .Net, i have simple echo client which does not support SSL and Proxy, but i need client which has got SSL implementation with Certificates (Self Signed)

I am using ClientWebSocket for connection (Websocket Server is in java).

How to share same self-signed certificate between websocket client(.net) and server (java) ?

I am trying to find some example but not getting anyhting, any direction would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure about what are you actually asking, but...

If you want to use a self-signed certificate for the client, you need to validate that certificate manually using : [ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx)

For the sake of testing, you can do:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

But when moving to production you should remove this code or put an actual certification validation code.

Comment: I am doing the same thing as you explained but it gives me error server returned error code '200' when '101' was expected. It works correctly on browser (when i try to connect to websocket server)

Comment: 200 is not an error code, it means that the HTTP request was successful. So probably you are doing something that prevents the acceptance of the websocket connection (which would return the 101 code) or you are just connecting to the wrong endpoint/url (so it is assuming a normal GET request, and therefore returning a 200 code). I think it should be probably the second option. You should show more code.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution will not work for the **ClientWebSocket** connection.

```
 webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
 webSocket.Options.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback += (o, c, ch, er) => true;
```

Will emphasize one more time

> when moving to production you should remove this code or put an actual certification validation code.